# Unable to download large files from Sonatype Nexus

Tags: nexus, sonatype, maven-central

Nexus version 3.1.0-04

During a build, I receive the following error downloading an artifact from Nexus.

> Download >http://10.148.254.17:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/assertj/assertj-core/2.4.1/assertj-core-2.4.1.jar
>   :collection:extractIncludeTestProto FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':collection:testCompile'.
>     Could not download assertj-core.jar (org.assertj:assertj-core:2.4.1)
>     Could not get resource 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/assertj/assertj-core/2.4.1/assertj-core-2.4.1.jar'.
>     Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 900718; received: 6862

This appear to be a problem with large files stored in Nexus.

If I try and download the file via wget or curl, it also fails.

c:>wget http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/assertj/assertj-core/2.5.0/assertj-
core-2.5.0.jar

> --13:57:06--  >http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/assertj/assertj-core/2.5.0/assertj-core-2.5.0.jar
>              => `assertj-core-2.5.0.jar'
>   Resolving proxy.xxxx.com... done.
>   Connecting to proxy.xxxx.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:xxx... connected.
>   Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>   Length: 934,446 [application/java-archive]
>
> 0% [                                     ] 6,856          1.44K/s    ETA 10:27
>
> 13:57:21 (1.44 KB/s) - Connection closed at byte 6856. Retrying.

c:>curl -O http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/assertj/assertj-core/2.5.0/assertj-core-2.5.0.jar

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>     0  912k    0  6862    0     0    613      0  0:25:24  0:00:11  0:25:13   613
>   curl: (18) transfer closed with 927584 bytes remaining to read

Any ideas why?

Comment: This isn't really a large file, checking Maven Central it's only 600kb more or less, and we've seen MUCH larger files going in and out of Nexus Repository. File an issue here to begin with: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS , and maybe try moving to the newest version as well (3.2.1 as of today).

Comment: Just upgraded to Nexus 3.2.1, same results with every operation above.

Comment: It looks like this was also filed as a Jira ticket.  The answer is here:  https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12435?focusedCommentId=395835&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-395835  ... a local virus scanner is interfering with these downloads.

Answer (score 1):

In my case by docker layer was blocked. I solved this problem by changing the timeout in `System>Http>Connection/Socket timeout`.